# How to find records with mutiple relations to a second table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm finding records from table `tablea` that are related to a record in `tableb`.
I use the in function `IN (1)` to find `tablea` records that are related to `tableb` record 1. I use `IN` because the value in the brackets could be a comma-separated list.

I now have to do the same, but `tablea` records should be related to all `tableb` records, not just any of them, which is what `IN` finds.

What function can I use instead of `IN` to do this?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablea 
    JOIN tablec ON tablea.id = tablec.id_local 
    JOIN tableb ON tablec.id_foreign = tableb.id 
WHERE 
    tablea.lang IN ( 0 ) 
AND tablea.page >=1 
AND tablea.page IN ( 8, 9, 10, 11 ) 
AND tableb.id = 5 
ORDER BY tablea.datetime DESC
```

The above works,

but `tableb.id` now could be several, as `tablea` records can be related to mutiple `tableb` records.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
JOIN tablec ON tablea.id = tablec.id_local
JOIN tableb ON tablec.id_foreign = tableb.id
WHERE
    tablea.lang IN ( 0 )
AND tablea.page >=1
AND tablea.page
IN ( 8, 9, 10, 11 )
AND tableb.id IN (5,6,7)
ORDER BY tablea.datetime DESC
```

This sort of works. It finds `tablea` records that are related to any of the `tableb` records (5,6,7), but how can I change my SQL so that it finds `tablea` records that are related to all the `tableb` records (5,6, and 7)?

Comment: Could you please post your current query and state the fields that need to now match?

Comment: I think I'm lost now, would you mind giving some functional details? I kind of think you are joining twice your tables, but I'm not sure. To investigate I need to know what you are really doing, and for instance what are these numbers

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any field names, so I'm using `relatedfield` as the field name that correlates between the two tables:

```
SELECT *  
FROM tablea 
    JOIN tableb ON (tablea.relatedfield = tableb.relatedfield)
```